# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

Если честно, даже предположений нет в чём ошибка. Возникает после запуска в одном из двух мест, в зависимости от того, какое из чисел больше

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random RandNum = new Random();
            bool even;
            int MaxEvNum = 0;
            int MaxNotEvNum = 0;
            int[] AON = new int[200];
            foreach (int el in AON)
            {
                AON[el] = Convert.ToInt32(RandNum.Next(0, 10001));
                even = Convert.ToBoolean((AON[el] % 2) == 0);
                if ((even == true) && (AON[el] > MaxEvNum))
                    MaxEvNum = Convert.ToInt32(AON[el]);
                else
                    if ((even == false) && (AON[el] > MaxNotEvNum))
                    MaxNotEvNum = Convert.ToInt32(AON[el]);

            }
            if (MaxEvNum > MaxNotEvNum)
                foreach (int el in AON)
                {
                    // Здесь выходит ошибка
                    even = ((AON[el] % 2) == 0);
                    if (even == false)
                    {
                        AON[el] = 0;
                    }
                }
            else
                foreach (int el in AON)
                {
                    // Или здесь
                    even = ((AON[el] % 2) == 0);
                    if (even == true)
                    {
                        AON[el] = 0;
                    }
                }
                foreach (int el in AON)
                    Console.WriteLine(AON[el]);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы перепутали циклы `for` и `foreach`. `foreach` вот так работает `foreach (int el in AON) Console.WriteLine(el);` где `el` это элемент, а не индекс, а вы его используете как индекс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < AON.Length; i++)
{
    // Здесь не выходит ошибка
    even = ((AON[i] % 2) == 0);
    if (even == false)
    {
        AON[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

Comment: Спасибо, ребята, не знаю сколько бы я потратил времени на поиск решения без вашей помощи)))

Comment: @bbdemond Пожалуйста. Успехов.